# Sharepoint web-form submit Thanks Message issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, webforms, page-lifecycle

I have a web-part that includes a simple web form. After submitting the web form, the user sees a thank you or an error message.

It is in a codeBehind on `Click_event`:

```
lblMessage.Text = "Your Profile Details were updated successfully";
```

And code in the asxc file:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

The problem is that the message doesn't disappear after the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit F5 this is refreshing the page to it's original state where the label doesn't have any text as you showed.  The only way for your label to have that text is to go through the button click event.

> Looks like you need to read some info on page life cycles and view
>   state:
>
> http://rameshsps2010.blogspot.com/2011/06/sp-and-aspnet-page-life-cycle.html
>
> http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/understanding-web-part-life-cycle/
>
> http://www.sharepointdotnet.com/2012/02/page-lifecycle-events-in-aspnet.html